# htaccess style login for drupal

Tags: 7

I want a separate login for my site for Drupal. One to simply access the page, the same functionality that an .htaccess login would provide.

Except I want it to be styled as a separate html page, not as the default module popup htaccess does.

Is there a Drupal module for this or do I need a simple PHP script outside Drupal.

Comment: I think this is issue is a duplicate of this one http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9631/how-to-restrict-access-to-the-site-during-development

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Secure Site](http://drupal.org/project/securesite) module could be the best choice:

> This module allows you to authenticate users with a browser-based
>   password (HTTP Auth). You can restrict access to the site by role and
>   choose to secure restricted pages or the entire site. This means the
>   site will be inaccessible to search engines and other crawlers, but
>   you can still allow access to certain users.

You can change the settings to use a page instead the popup. It's also possible to theme the login page - [see the information here](http://drupal.org/node/328196).

Answer (score 1):

The [Protected Node module](http://drupal.org/project/protected_node) allows you to optionally set passwords on nodes.